# Plone, creating a viewlet from a form

Tags: plone

I have a snippet of HTML content that I constantly have to update on my homepage. I ideally want to go to a page, fill in a form, and have that form data populate the HTML snippet (viewlet?)

Open to any suggestions. (creating a custom content type, using mysql db to populate it. anything!)

Comment: Why can't you just edit the homepage? Is this snippet outside of the main editable content area? If so, where?

Comment: Please attach a screenshot or provide more information about what you want.

Comment: Yes it was outside of the editable area. In the header on the front page only. I have to edit that area constantly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this elegantly with a marker interface and [archetypes.schemaextender](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/archetypes.schemaextender). Assuming your homepage is set up like the front-page on a fresh Plone site - a Document made the default view of the Plone site - add to your custom product's `interfaces.py`:

```
class IHomepage(Interface):
    """Marker interface flagging a document as the homepage.
    """
```

And to `configure.zcml`:

```
<class class="Products.ATContentTypes.interfaces.document.IATDocument">
  <allow interface=".interfaces.IHomepage" />
</class>
```

In the ZMI, on the Interfaces tab for the front-page, set `IHomepage` as a provided interface.

Now you can register a schemaextender that applies only to your front-page object.

Create a new file `schemaextender.py`.

```
from zope.component import adapts
from zope.interface import implements

from Products.Archetypes import atapi

from archetypes.schemaextender.field import ExtensionField
from archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces import ISchemaExtender

from interfaces import IHomepage

class HomepageBlurbTextField(ExtensionField, atapi.TextField):
    """Extra text for the homepage.
    """

class HomepageExtender(object):
    adapts(IHomepage)
    implements(ISchemaExtender)

    fields = [
        HomepageBlurbTextField('blurb',
            required=True,
            searchable=True,
            storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
            validators=('isTidyHtmlWithCleanup',),
            default_output_type='text/x-html-safe',
            widget=atapi.RichWidget(
                label=u"Blurb",
                description=u"Make the site sound cool.",
                rows=25,
                allow_file_upload=False),
        ),

    ]

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context

    def getFields(self):
        return self.fields
```

Add to `configure.zcml`:

```
<adapter factory=".schemaextender.HomepageExtender" />
```

(This is a simple example; see archetypes.schemaextender's docs for more advanced features like field reordering, registering only to a specific browser layer, etc.)

Restart the site, edit the front-page and - hey presto - a new field for your blurb.

Now all you have to do is display it. You can do what you like here, just remember to register for your `IHomepage` interface. Let's say you wanted the blurb to appear in the page's header:

In `browser/viewlets.py`:

```
from Acquisition import aq_inner
from plone.app.layout.viewlets import common

class HomepageHeaderViewlet(common.ViewletBase):

    @property
    def blurb(self):
        context = aq_inner(self.context)
        return context.getField('blurb').get(context)
```

In `browser/homepageheader.pt`:

```
<div id="homepage-blurb" tal:content="structure view/blurb|nothing" />
```

In `browser/configure.zcml`:

```
<browser:viewlet
    name="example.homepageheader"
    for="..interfaces.IHomepage"
    manager="plone.app.layout.viewlets.interfaces.IPortalTop"
    class=".viewlets.HomepageHeaderViewlet"
    template="homepageheader.pt"
    permission="zope.Public"
    />
```

Comment: "In the ZMI, on the Interfaces tab for the front-page, set IHomepage as a provided interface."... do i set IHomepage as an interface as soon as I have completed the preceding step? IHomepage is not showing up as an option, even after restarting zope and rerunning buildout

Comment: @yanyanyang I tested this code before posting, so I'm confident it'll work for you. Try changing the `configure.zcml` code to `<interface interface=".interfaces.IHomepage" />`. Otherwise, check that everything is being loaded by making a deliberate syntax error and making sure Zope complains about it on startup. If you get it working please accept my answer!

Comment: It is not registering correctly. I threw in some craziness into the python file and I get no errors when running buildout.

Comment: @yanyanyang buildout wouldn't throw errors on bad Python in your package. Put something odd into your `configure.zcml` and check Zope startup complains. I assume you've taken all the steps described [here](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/managing-projects-with-buildout/creating-a-new-package)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your usecase but often you can get by without coding using something like collective.portletpage with several static text portlets to create the page you want. With plone.app.theming you have the ability to rearrage the html for your needs.

for example our new homepage http://www.pretaweb.com was done using plone.app.theming, collective.portletpage and Products.ContentWellPortlets.

Products.Collage is another alternative to portletpage we've also used.